# Setting the nth member of a void* in a struct (and struct name usage vs. typedef)

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

For a Risk-like game I have a struct for each region, each of which need to have a list of associated regions that troops can move into from the mother region.

In theory, it would look like

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    region_t* connections;
} region_t;
```

However, this is of course impossible due to the fact that region_t doesn't exist before the parser reaches the type region_t*. Therefore I have opted to use void* in place of region_t*.

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    void* connections;
} region_t;

MiddleEast.connections = malloc(6 * sizeof(void*));
MiddleEast.connections = &SouthernEurope;
MiddleEast.(connections + 1) = &Egypt;
```

Using the `region_t`s `MiddleEast`, `SouthernEurope`, and `Egypt`, I can set the first connection to `Southern Europe` successfully, but when I try to set `.(connections + 1)` to `&Egypt` I get the compiler error

`error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token`

How do I properly access the next memory address?

Comment: No, you can. typedef struct region{
    char* name;
    struct region* connections;
} region_t;//did you hear about linked lists?

Comment: @purec oh that's right. I've been so wrapped up in typedefs that I forgot structs can also have names :-)

Comment: Regarding `MiddleEast.(connections + 1) = &Egypt;`, the correct syntax for this is `MiddleEast.connections + 1 = &Egypt;`, but this again will not work as intended. The working code would be `MiddleEast.connections + sizeof(region_t) = &Egypt;` (because it was declared `void *` and the increment does not work automatically with `sizeof`). Just for the sake of memory arithmetic :)

Comment: Indeed something along `*(region_t*)(void*)((uintptr_t)MiddleEast.connections + sizeof(region_t)) = &Egypt` would work, but is just pain in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is not `void *`, it's properly using structs.

structs with a name can be referenced inside themselves. The type doesn't exist, but the named struct does, so you can write:

```
typedef struct region{
    char* name;
    struct region* connections;
} region_t;
```

Comment: It is not correct to say “The type doesn’t exist.” Once `struct identifier` has appeared in the code, `struct identifier` is known to the compiler as an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an array of void pointers, not an array of voids. You want to iterate over void pointers.

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    void **connections;
} region_t;

MiddleEast.connections = malloc(6 * sizeof(void*));
MiddleEast.connections[0] = &SouthernEurope;
MiddleEast.connections[1] = &Egypt;
free(MiddleEast.connections);
```

> is of course impossible due to the fact that region_t doesn't exist before the parser reaches the type region_t*.

You can't forward declare a typedef, but you can do that with structure.

```
typedef struct region_s {
   char *name;
   struct region_s *connections;
} region_t;
```

Forward declaration is common in C code in constructing linked lists and similar. The `sizeof(struct region_s *)` is known, the `struct region_s` pointer size is known before the `struct region_s` is defined, so you can:

```
// forward declaration
struct region_s;
// pointer is ok
struct region_s *regionpointer;
// we can define the structure after using a pointer
struct region_s {
    // you can even point to yourself
    struct region_s *regionpointer;
};
// typedef separated for readbility
typedef struct region_s region_t;
```

> error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token

```
MiddleEast.(connections + 1) = &Egypt;
```

The `.` is member operator; it gets the member of a structure. The string after `.` is taken as a symbol. As you can see, there is no member inside `MiddleEast` structure named `(connections` (exactly, using space as separator), as such name is disallowed. You want:

```
MiddleEast.connections + 1 = &Egypt;
```

Which will still not work, as the left side of `=` is the value of the pointer inside `MiddleEast.connections` array. You can't assign this value; it is a result of an addition. (the same you can't `int a; a + 5 = 43;`). What you want is to assign the value of the second element inside `MiddleEast.connections` array to the value of `&Egypt`. So you need to deference the pointer value.

```
*(MiddleEast.connections + 1) = &Egypt;
```

Or shorter and way more readable, as `a[b]` is equal to `*(a + b)`:

```
MiddleEast.connections[1] = &Egypt;
```

Jokingly: Please never:

```
1[MiddleEast.connections] = &Egypt;
```

The `MiddleEast.connections` is an "integral"/whole/standalone part, that you can't separate.

Note that doing:

```
MiddleEast.connections = malloc(6 * sizeof(void*));
MiddleEast.connections = &SouthernEurope;
```

just leaks memory, as you can't no longer `free(MiddleEast.connections)` free the memory.

Comment: note that `MiddleEast.connections + 1` causes `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: @KamilCuk You are able to `free(MiddleEast.connections)` (if declared on heap). But indeed it doesn't free what you allocated before, so yes, there is definitely a memory leak.

Comment: @VladRusu can you explain why free(MiddleEast.connections) doesn't free the allocated data?

Comment: @Stegosaurus You first assigned `MiddleEast.connections = malloc(6 * sizeof(void*));`. Which means that now `MiddleEast.connections` points to the newly allocated memory. Now if you make `MiddleEast.connections = &SouthernEurope;` you lose the reference to the allocated memory. When you call free afterwards, you won't free what you allocated before, but you will free the memory where `&SouthernEurope` points to.